# How can you tell whether a file is being cached in memory in linux?

Tags: linux, file, memory, caching

Essentially my question is, does anyone know of a utility for inspecting the **buffer cache** in linux?

Comment: The linux kernel doesn't cache files, it caches blocks. A file may consist of many blocks, some of which may be cached and some which may not. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at [linux-ftools](http://code.google.com/p/linux-ftools/). This suite of tools is specifically designed to analyze the buffers and cache. It includes the following tools:

- fincore
- fadvise
- fallocate

Of these 3 tools the one that will show you the list of files in the buffers & cache is `fincore`.

```
$ fincore [options] files...

  --pages=false      Do not print pages
  --summarize        When comparing multiple files, print a summary report
  --only-cached      Only print stats for files that are actually in cache.

root@xxxxxx:/var/lib/mysql/blogindex# fincore --pages=false --summarize --only-cached * 
stats for CLUSTER_LOG_2010_05_21.MYI: file size=93840384 , total pages=22910 , cached pages=1 , cached size=4096, cached perc=0.004365 
stats for CLUSTER_LOG_2010_05_22.MYI: file size=417792 , total pages=102 , cached pages=1 , cached size=4096, cached perc=0.980392 
stats for CLUSTER_LOG_2010_05_23.MYI: file size=826368 , total pages=201 , cached pages=1 , cached size=4096, cached perc=0.497512 
stats for CLUSTER_LOG_2010_05_24.MYI: file size=192512 , total pages=47 , cached pages=1 , cached size=4096, cached perc=2.127660 
...
```

Comment: Unfortunately these tools are not available in most linux distributions by default (I checked Ubuntu and SuSE, I have no redhat at hand).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure if you're asking what I think you're asking, but [vmtouch](http://hoytech.com/vmtouch/) could be helpful to you. Just type `vmtouch [file or folder you want to check for presence in cache]`